# Purpose of CALayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-animation, appkit

I'm slightly used as to what the purpose of CALayer's existence is. Why not just put the properties in a UIView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CALayer represents a completely different "thing" from a UIView.  A CALayer only deals with drawing itself, and encapsulating the information needed to do that.  A view, on the other hand, owns one or many layers, which it uses to draw itself.  A view has many other functions and properties though, that are unrelated to its representation on the screen.

I would recommend digging into the Apple documentation, and maybe picking up a book on Object Oriented coding.

Comment: Right, so why not just add the properties that the layer would have directly to the view?

Comment: That's the whole point of object based coding.  Objects should be responsible for well defined parts of behavior, and nothing else.  What you're describing is a classic case of the "God Object", and is explicitly contrary to good object oriented design.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object